# JSON object is NULL when data from URL is small?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object im decoding from a url like so:

```
    $var = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

The data i am getting is from the new battle.net API that is returned as a JSON object containing character data.

- Here is an actual link where the character is found and there is data to be generated: [Character Found](http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/Mannoroth/Anadia?fields=achievements).
- Now here is a link for a character that does not exist and generates and error: [Character Not Found](http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/Smolderthorn/Sidratha?fields=achievements).

Errors are returned as JSON objects that contain "status" and "reason" attributes. The value of the "status" attribute will always be "nok".

**My problem is when the character is NOT FOUND the JSON object $var is NULL where if it is FOUND the JSON object $var contains the correct data. I need to be able to check whether the status is "nok" so i can output the apropriate error message**

I have:

- Checked the links to make sure they are generating correctly.
- Changed `json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true)` to: `json_decode(file_get_contents($url), false)` and tried accessing $var as an object.
- Tried using cURL instead of `file_get_contents($url)`

I posted on the battle.net API forums but i thought i would try here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the page Character Not Found page returns a `404 Not Found` HTTP response code, which makes a lot of sense, but is considered an error.

File functions, such as `file_get_contents`, will return `false` by default when encountering an error (404, 500, etc.) on a HTTP stream wrapper.

In order to ignore the error and return the content anyway, so that `json_decode` can parse it, you need to use a context:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$var = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context), true);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, i had read on using stream contexts but i did not find anything that seemed related.